# What exactly is "/d/msdownload/update/software/defu/2020/06/am_delta_patch_1.317.1140.0_b3f0b7db16f7b0cfd8020b9ab4ae61349300d9d1.exe"?

Tags: windows-10, security, privacy

Suddenly logged in my PHP localhost dev server:

> [Fri Jun 12 17:19:09 2020] 127.0.0.1:58391 [404]: (null) /d/msdownload/update/software/defu/2020/06/am_delta_patch_1.317.1140.0_b3f0b7db16f7b0cfd8020b9ab4ae61349300d9d1.exe - No such file or directory

Why is Windows 10 (apparently) making HTTP requests to 127.0.0.1 for .exe files? Seems to be related to Windows updates somehow, judging by the path requested, but why would it be fetching this from **LOCALHOST**, and with HTTP? Would this not be something fetched from Microsoft's servers with some completely different, encrypted protocol?

Also, I have turned off all the "fetch updates in a P2P manner" madness, so it can't be that. (But even if it were, it would still not make any sense and be just as confusing.)

Bottom line: **Why is Windows 10 apparently trying to fetch updates from my localhost development webserver?**

I have noticed this happening at least once before, months ago, but of course it could happen regularly except I don't notice it. But why is it doing it in the first place? What could possibly explain this?

I have searched for the path, and parts of it, surprisingly finding zero results online.

Comment: You will have to provide more information.  Have you modified the hosts file on this machine?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is Windows 10 apparently trying to fetch updates from my localhost development webserver?

My guess is that you added several Microsoft CDN domains to your /etc/hosts, perhaps in an attempt to block a MS webservice or to disable telemetry or other "madness".

Usually such blocklists don't really *block* the domain, they redirect it to 127.0.0.1 – i.e. localhost. This only happens to work for most people because they don't run webservers.

> Would this not be something fetched from Microsoft's servers with some completely different, encrypted protocol?

No, Windows Update has always used HTTP(S). It's the current protocol of choice for delivering any kind of static files, allowing the same CDN to be used for everything.

It is more important for the *data* to be authenticated and/or encrypted, and Windows updates are digitally signed using Authenticode (digital certificates chaining from a dedicated CA), so the lack of TLS is not much of an issue. You'll see the same situation on e.g. Debian or Arch Linux.